# Enable chatter feed for custom object in managed package

Tags: chatter-feed-tracking

I have a custom object in a managed package for which feed tracking is not enabled. However, in a new version, I have enabled feed tracking for the object(not for any fields) and this works well in the package installation but does not enable feed tracking for an object in package upgrade.

I am not very clear from any of the salesforce documentation if is this a known limitation. Also, can we enable feed tracking for an object programmatically?